# Inserting Lines into a Non-Text File

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to insert lines into the middle of a non-text file (the extension of the file is "dxf"). I am using vbscript to do this.

Everywhere I have look, I come across the FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile. However, when I try to use this on a dxf file, it is causing an error: Exception 80070057 (I believe this is an invalid file) .

Here is my code:

```
Dim file
Dim fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fileexists(dxfFile$) Then
    Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(dxfPath, ForAppending, True)

    file.WriteLine("<PORTLIST TESTING>ASDFLKJ")
    file.Close
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `dxfFile$` is not a valid VBscript variable name; use `dxfFile`, `file` or `dfxPath` (consistently)
2. `FileExists` is a method of the FileSystemObject; you need to call `fso.FileExists`
3. Neither `dxfFile`, nor `dfxPath`, nor `ForAppending` are defined
4. Calling `.OpenTextFile` with an undefined/empty first/filespec parameter throws an error 5 - Invalid procedure call or argument
5. You can't **insert** lines by **appending** them; modifying files 'in the middle' is especially clumsy in VBScript; loading the whole file into memory, editing, writing it back may work for you
6. .DFX file come in ASCII or binary format; if the latter, you can't use the FileSystemObject (see ADODB.Stream)

Comment: I simply had to exchange the ForAppending with 8